# Could not create stateless EJB with JPA

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to insert some data to DB with EJB and JPA. When I execute the code i got the `serverError: class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB` error. Here my code. I have try lot of by changing various things. what is that error occurred? I think my Entity manager initialization has some wrong

```
 DesignationEntity de = new DesignationEntity();
        de.setDesignationName(this.designationName);
        de.setDesignationDescription(this.designationDescription);
        ds.addDesignationDb(de);
```

**EJB service class**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DesignationService {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ecs2complainmanager")
    private EntityManager em;

    public DesignationService() {
    }



    public void addDesignationDb(DesignationEntity de){
        em.persist(de);
    }
}


Entity class

@Entity
public class DesignationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Integer designationId;

    private String designationName;

    private String designationDescription;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "designationId")
    private UserEntity user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getDesignationId() {
        return designationId;
    }

    public void setDesignationId(Integer designationId) {
        this.designationId = designationId;
    }

    public String getDesignationName() {
        return designationName;
    }

    public void setDesignationName(String designationName) {
        this.designationName = designationName;
    }

    public String getDesignationDescription() {
        return designationDescription;
    }

    public void setDesignationDescription(String designationDescription) {
        this.designationDescription = designationDescription;
    }

    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@PersistenceUnit` is the cause. After I changed it to `@PersistenceContext`